# No funciona la consulta, no detecta letras

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy tratando de hacer una consulta en PHP y MYSQL, pero ésta no me funciona,

`'grado'` es un número, por ejemplo 2. Si realizo la consulta solo con `'grado'` si funciona, pero si pruebo con `'grupo'` que es un letra, por ejemplo B, no funciona, es como si no detectara las letras del alfabeto.

```
$grado=$_GET['grado']; 
$grupo=$_GET['grupo']; 
$sql = "* FROM usuarios WHERE grado = $grado  AND grupo = $grupo";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El problema es que no estás escapando la letra. Tu query debería lucir de esta manera:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE grado = $grado  AND grupo = '$grupo'";
//---------------------------------------------------------------^------^
```

De todas maneras, sería mejor si tu query lo ejecutas de forma preparada y no directamente:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE grado = ? AND grupo = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("is", $grado, $grupo);
```

De esta manera evitas problemas de inyección de SQL en tu aplicación.

Comment: muchas gracias @Luiggi Mendoza, ya me funciona gracias por el apoyo

Answer (score 2):

Los textos tienen que ir encerrados con comillas simples:

```
$sql = "* FROM usuarios WHERE grado = $grado AND grupo = '$grupo'";
```

En cualquier caso más te vale asegurarte de que tanto `$grado`, como `$grupo` son seguras antes de meterlas a piñón en la consulta.

Hay un fallo de seguridad bastante serio denominado `SQL Injection` que permitiría ejecutar consultas aleatorias en tu portal.

Comment: Muchas gracias @eferion ya corregi y esta funcionando

Answer (score 1):

## Lo has intentado de esta forma?

```
$grado = $_GET['grado'];
$grupo = $_GET['grupo'];

if ( isset($grado) && isset($grupo) ) {

    $sql = "* FROM usuarios WHERE grado = ".$grado."  AND grupo = ".$grupo;

    if ( $result = $conn - > query($sql) ) {
        echo 'Correcto'; // funciona....
    };

} else {
    echo 'fallo en parametros';
}
```

Comment: probare con esa forma, pero ya esta funcionando, gracias de todas formas