# ERROR: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in

Tags: php

El script que tengo aparentemente funciona, tengo el siguiente código en *PHP*:

```
$sql = "SELECT gcm_regid  FROM gcm_users WHERE papa1 = '$papa1'  AND  cel1 = '$cel1'"; 
echo $sql; 
$result = $conn->query($sql); 
if ($result->num_rows > 0) { 
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
        include_once '../gcm/GCM.php'; 
        $regId = $row["gcm_regid"]; 
        $message = $message; 
        echo $regId; 
        echo $message; 
        echo "entre"; 
        $gcm = new GCM(); 
        $registatoin_ids = array($regId); 
        $message = array("price" => $message); 
        $result = $gcm->send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message); 
        echo $result; 
    } 
} else { 
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

Pero me muestra el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in /public_html/gcm/run.php on line 46r

¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

Comment: ¿Cuál linea manda el fatal error? ¿Qué mensajes se muestran en el log de errores o en el navegador cuando se ejecuta este script?

Comment: Justo en donde inicia el ciclo  while, habla de un objeto, podría ser por $gcm = new GCM();

Comment: $papa1 y $cel1 al parecer son variables ¿Qué valores tienes ahí?

Comment: ¿Puedes por favor editar tu pregunta y colocar el stacktrace que te arroja PHP? De esa manera será más facil entender y revisar tu problema.

Comment: colocar esto como pregunta ? Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in /public_html/gcm/run.php on line 46

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error `"Call to a member function <función> on a non-object in"` sucede porque la variable, en este caso `$result`, no es un objeto y por tanto no se puede llamar el método o función esperado. Esto se explica mejor [acá (idioma inglés)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12769983/1065197).

El problema está en esta línea dentro del `while`:

```
$result = $gcm->send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message);
```

Estás sobreescribiendo la variable `$result`. Es muy probable que el nuevo valor de `$result` no sea el de ejecutar `$conn->query($sql)`, por ende el error. Te recomiendo que utilices otro nombre para esta variable local en el ciclo `while`.

---

Esto no es el problema real, pero mayormente es la causa. Lo dejo indicado por si alguien se topa con este problema por causa del query.

Cuando [`mysqli_query`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php) posee un error al procesar la sentencia SQL que posee, devuelve `falso` (énfasis mía):

> **Valores devueltos**
>
> **Retorna `FALSE` en caso de error.** Si una consulta del tipo `SELECT`, `SHOW`, `DESCRIBE` o `EXPLAIN` es exitosa, `mysqli_query()` retornará un objeto `mysqli_result`. Para otras consultas exitosas de `mysqli_query()` retornará `TRUE`.

Puede que el query retorne `false`. Es muy probable que el problema esté acá:

```
$sql = "SELECT gcm_regid  FROM gcm_users WHERE papa1 = '$papa1'  AND  cel1 = '$cel1'";
```

Esto puede suceder porque concatenas directamente los valores de `$papa1` y `$cel1` en tu query, y pueden poseer caracteres que rompan el query. Acá un ejemplo:

```
$papa1 = "papa";
$cel1 = "cel'"; //nota la comilla al final
$sql = "SELECT gcm_regid  FROM gcm_users WHERE papa1 = '$papa1'  AND  cel1 = '$cel1'";
echo $sql;
```

Que va a imprimir:

```
SELECT gcm_regid  FROM gcm_users WHERE papa1 = 'papa' AND cel1 = 'cel''
```

Y voalá, query destruido :D

Para evitar sanear los valores de estas variables en este y otros queries, te recomiendo ejecutar el query de manera preparada, tal como expliqué en [esta otra respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/3918/227).

Comment: Pienso lo mismo, ¿pero entonces no debería fallar en la fila anterior: `if ($result->num_rows > 0) {`?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro inspeccionando el código, encontré el error. Mira la edición. A fin de cuentas, son cosas que pasan.

Comment: No me había dado cuenta de eso. Entonces realmente falla en la segunda iteración y no en la primera. Buen ojo. Te daría otro +1 si el que tuvieras ahora mismo no fuera mío :)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro gracias a ti. Si no me comentabas lo del `num_rows` no hubiese leido todo el código a más detalle.

Comment: XD si, ya funciona corregi el result por res

Comment: De nada @JESUSESPINOSA y la verdad que te seguiré insistiendo en queu utilices `mysqli_prepare` y sentencias preparadas :P pero fuera de bromas es una buena práctica usar sentencias preparadas, con eso tus sentencias SQL son más seguras.

Comment: @JESUSESPINOSA haz lo que dice Luiggi, o te puedes encontrar con resultados indeseados. Imagina que en lugar del ejemplo `cel'`  el usuario pone como dato `'; DROP TABLE gcm_regid; --` y te borra toda la tabla.